# Intel SGX: Creating an attestation report within the enclave

Tags: intel, sgx, enclave

I'm using [SCONE](https://sconedocs.github.io/) Docker image to run my code inside Intel SGX enclave.

SCONE handles the creation of enclaves and their eventual destruction, which makes my life as a programmer easier. But if I want to perform a Local or Remote Attestation of my code inside the enclave, I need to rely on SCONE's proprietary service.

I wonder if it's possible to create a report for attestation from within the current enclave. In other words, the code running inside the enclave must be able to create an attestation report and send it out - all without leaving the enclave.

I've checked Intel SGX documentation and samples code. All of the calls to EREPORT function rely on knowing the Enclave ID, which I don't know (SCONE creates enclaves on my behalf). Hence my question is mainly about the way to find out the enclave information from within it.

Is it actually possible?